# Print Packing Slip "No Address Provided" via REST API C#

Tags: c#, paypal

Have successfully implemented PayPal.Api.Payments.Payer using:

PayPal.Api.Payments.Address billingAddress = new PayPal.Api.Payments.Address();
 ...
 creditCard.billing_address = billingAddress;

HOWEVER, when I look at the dashboard and go to print packing slip; I see "No Address Provided" and "The sender of this payment is Unregistered".

Does the buyer need to be "registered" with paypal for the shipping information to show up or am I not setting something correctly.  I have looked pretty extensively.  Billing info is set correctly.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, that worked.  Here is my working code for others.

PayPal.Api.Payments.Transaction transaction = new PayPal.Api.Payments.Transaction();
transaction.item_list.shipping_address.city = reader[5].ToString().Trim();
transaction.item_list.shipping_address.line1 = reader[2].ToString().Trim();
transaction.item_list.shipping_address.postal_code = reader[7].ToString().Trim();
transaction.item_list.shipping_address.state = reader[6].ToString().Trim();
transaction.item_list.shipping_address.country_code = reader[20].ToString().Trim();
transaction.amount = amount;
transaction.description = "xxx";

List transactions = new List();
transactions.Add(transaction);

all working now on http://niupure.com

Answer (score 0):

PayPal does not share billing information through transaction details. Because of this, you will need to set the `payment.transactions[0].item_list.shipping_address` as well as the billing information.